# How deny HTTPS request on IP and allow only with Domain name?

Tags: iis, web, https, ip, domain-name

How can i stop windows server 2008 R2 IIS-7 to response HTTPS request on IP, I want to allowed it only with Domain Name.
Example: https:/ipaddress - Block
         https:/domain.com - Allow